# How to get this Discord bot running with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

I've followed [this guide](https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/), but the bot doesn't go online

I'm using a Raspberry

- NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
- VERSION_ID="9"
- VERSION="9 (stretch)"
- ID=raspbian

,

- node version : 
  v10.15.0
- npm version : 
  6.4.1

I've created the files auth.json, package.json, and bot.js (code provided below)

`npm install discord.io winston --save` has created the dependencies in package.json

In one directory, I have the following 3 files :

auth.json

```
{
"token": "blhblhblh.blhblh.blhblhblh"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyBot123",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "author": "author",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.io": "^2.5.3",
    "winston": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

bot.js

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with !
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

The command `node bot.js` should run the bot, but it executes without any error message and the bot doesn't seem to go online. I'm quite confused and unable to debug this, as I have no experience with node.js , a first working code would help a ton. Thanks !

Comment: does it connect ? does it log in ?

Comment: @xyious I'm not sure how to determine that, but I'll try to understand better. Any hint is welcome, thanks !

Comment: the bot doesn't actually go online on Discord, if that was the question